# Vectores y Listas en C++

Tags: c++

Estoy aprendiendo C++ y tengo dudas con el uso de listas. Estoy programando con Sublime Text en Linux. El siguiente codigo da el problema de compilación **'vector' was not declared in this scope**.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(10);

    return 0;
}
```

Tengo conocimientos de C# en el cual las declaraciones son muy intuitivas y en C++ me esta costando trabajo la relacion con las librerias. Si me pueden ayudar con la declaracion correcta? Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No funciona porque vector esta declarado en el espacio de nombre std. Puedes usar

```
using namespace std;
```

para poder usar todos los elementos del espacio de nombre std. Declarando esto te evitarías muchas veces el `std::` que se utiliza con los elementos de la STL.

Answer (score 1):

Declara la variable `std::vector<int> v` en vez de como la tienes declarada.

[Referencias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5239882/what-is-the-need-to-specify-std-prefix)